# XML turns to Chinese/Japanese while Importing column using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, etl

**Scenario :**  I have a file path (`E:\..\abc.xml`) in a variable, I need to import the content of that file into a table.

**XML Content:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x:books xmlns:x="urn:books">
   <book id="bk001">
      <author>Writer</author>
      <title>The First Book</title>
      <genre>Fiction</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <pub_date>2000-10-01</pub_date>
      <review>An amazing story of nothing.</review>
   </book>

   <book id="bk002">
      <author>Poet</author>
      <title>The Poet's First Poem</title>
      <genre>Poem</genre>
      <price>24.95</price>
      <pub_date>2011-11-11</pub_date>
      <review>Least poetic poems.</review>
   </book>
</x:books>
```

I used [this link](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/import-column-transformation-in-ssis/) to insert the content to the table. So the issue is, the package is running successfully but the inserted content is of not XML content, it's in other language (Chinese or Japanese).

Here is my package

[image]

`Get Filepath`, transforms the variable to a output column, so the output column `XMLFile` has the location `E:\..\abc.xml`

Here is my `Import Column` configuration

[image]

[image]

[image]

My output for this is

[image]

Any advise would be helpful.

Comment: What does the input XML file look like?

Comment: It's an ordinary XML file, I've updated the question with the XML content.

Comment: The datatype of the destination column is the XML datatype?

Comment: @TT. yes. Its of XML datatype

Comment: Perhaps the encoding of the XML file is in UTF-8, and SQL Server expects it to be in UTF-16. This is just a wild guess though, but SQL Server typically expects everything in UTF-16. Perhaps there is an option to specify the encoding of the source file in SSIS?

Comment: @TT. Checked for that unicode settings. Couldn't find that in any of that components :(

Comment: Have you tried importing to an NVARCHAR(MAX) column instead, or a VARCHAR(MAX)? Same effect? If not, you could do post ops to convert a better import to the final XML column... just an idea.

Answer (score 2):

The issue may be caused by a datatype conflict, just try to change the destination column datatype fron `DT_NTEXT` to `DT_WSTR` with length = 4000

**If it doesn`t work**

Follow the suggestions in the following links:

- [SSIS 2008R2 - Loading an XML file into a single column (with complications...)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4ba4fa30-9a2b-4c18-934a-66adb013d666/ssis-2008r2-loading-an-xml-file-into-a-single-column-with-complications?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [Import Xml nodes as Xml column with SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132186/import-xml-nodes-as-xml-column-with-ssis)

**Workaround**

Try inserting data to a stagging table (column type NVarchar) the use an Execute SQL statment to transfer data to the destination.

Comment: Thanks Hadi. I'm using a staging table and used Bulk insert using SQL query, which works by the way. But I'm trying to eliminate the query part. That's why, used import column. I tried this solution, but still didn't work :(